# wordpress - load script on specific page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i'm new on wordpress, i have cities pages "www.mysite.it/city" for each state of my country.

now i would like load a google analitycs script for each city, i'm tryng like this:

**Header.php**

```
if(is_page('city_1'))
    $img_src = 'city_1_image.jpg';
    $city_id_google = 'UA-97242948-24';

if(is_page('city_2'))
    $img_src = 'city_2_image.jpg';
    $city_id_google = 'UA-97242948-7';  
....

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...

</head>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<?php echo $city_id_google ?>"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '<?php echo $city_id_google ?>');
</script>
```

Like this i always see for all pages the first "$city_id_google" that i loaded, maybe cache wordpress ? maybe can i do it with JS is better?

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use wordpress [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

```
// This will be the default value and will use if there's no custom field value
$city_id_google = 'UA-97242948-7';

// get the UA from custom field value
$city_id_google_from_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_meta_key_you_assign', true);

// Override $city_id_google if custom field has value
if ( $city_id_google_from_meta  ) $city_id_google = $city_id_google_from_meta;
```

Or only load the script if there's custom field meta value

```
//get post meta value
$city_id_google_from_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_meta_key_you_assign', true);

// check if meta key has value 
if ( $city_id_google_from_meta  ) { ?>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<?php echo $city_id_google_from_meta ?>"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', '<?php echo $city_id_google_from_meta; ?>');
    </script>
<?php }
```

Also check [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) if you want to run something on specific